# can't use p:selectOneRadio tag

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

how can i use this tag :

```
<p:selectOneRadio>
```

i have a message error :

> the comonent library
>   http://primefaces.rpime.com.t/ui
>   doen't contain such comonent.

i already imported the primefaces jar and imported the namepace too :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    >
```

Comment: i fixed the bug, by rebuilding the project

Answer (score 1):

It has been [introduced](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/primefaces-3-0-m1-arrives/) in PrimeFaces version 3.0 M1. Prior this version it simply doesn't exist, which is exactly what the error message is trying to tell you. [Upgrade](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html) your PrimeFaces libraries or use the standard `<h:selectOneRadio>` instead.

Comment: @BalusC yes i know im already using primefaces-3.0.M1.jar but can't use that tag

Comment: Either you've the older version still in your classpath, or you're not using the M1 as you can *currently* download from the site.

Comment: Wait, who is giving the error message? JSF/PrimeFaces itself or the IDE (the editor) you're using? If the latter, just ignore and run it.

Comment: I have this error in the IDE :

the comonent library http://primefaces.rpime.com.t/ui doen't contain such comonent.

And this in JSF/PrimeFaces :
/calcul.xhtml @28,51 <p:selectOneRadio> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui, but no tag was defined for name: selectOneRadio

Comment: As said, ignore and run it. Does it get rendered? If so, then it's just missing in the taglib descriptor. This is not unusual for beta versions of PrimeFaces. If not, then you still have an older PrimeFaces version in the classpath which got precedence in classloading.

Comment: if i ignore it, im having JSF error too in the browser, i fixed the bug, by rebuilding the project :)

Answer (score 0):

*PrimeFaces 3.0* is still under development. The `selectOneRadio` is one of the new things that arrived with it. Then, use the **3.0.M1** if you really need those components.

Comment: yes i know im already using primefaces-3.0.M1.jar but can't use that tag

Comment: Well, I really don't think that using a pre-beta like it is very good. You can be hitting any beta bug. Maybe you can use `<h:selectOneRadio>` by now. It isn't themable, but works while the 3.0 isn't finished.

Comment: right, but this beta got lot of amazing components i fixed the bug, by rebuilding the project :)